# maven user prompt works from windows cmd, not from cygwin

Tags: maven, cygwin

I recently reinstalled cygwin from fresh, and am now seeing an issue with Maven builds.

A specific maven plugin I am attempting to use pops up an interactive prompt...

From the windows cmd, the user can enter their info:

```
What is the feature branch name? foo
```

From cygwin, it appears that maven keeps recieving some form of newline, because I see:

```
What is the feature branch name? What is the feature branch name? 
What is the feature branch name? What is the feature branch name? etc...
```

Has anyone else seen this, know how to fix this?

Comment: Show us the code! (your pom)

Answer (score 2):

> Has anyone else seen this, know how to fix this?

Yes, and there are several developers who seem to have a fix for it. Look in Jira for the [Maven and Mojo projects](https://jira.codehaus.org/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22cygwin%22) and search for cygwin. You'll see equivalent issues and a lot of them have been fixed.